# Motherboard Asus MAXIMUS VIII HERO Bluetooth and wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, bluetooth

I was just wondering if the Asus MAXIMUS VII HERO had Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. I am considering using this board and I can't find out if it does. (Searched for a long time) Thanks in advance, ~Tech22

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't have wifi, nor bluetooth.

See the spec (those would have been mentioned if it had them):  http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VII_HERO/HelpDesk_Manual/